# What would be a sensible way to implement a Trie in .NET?

Tags: .net, data-structures, dictionary, implementation, trie

I get the concept behind a [**trie**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). But I get a little confused when it comes to implementation.

The most obvious way I could think to structure a `Trie` type would be to have a `Trie` maintain an internal `Dictionary<char, Trie>`. I have in fact written one this way, and it *works*, but... this seems like overkill. My impression is that a trie should be lightweight, and having a separate `Dictionary<char, Trie>` for *every node* does not seem very lightweight to me.

Is there a more appropriate way to implement this structure that I'm missing?

---

**UPDATE**: OK! Based on the very helpful input from Jon and leppie, this is what I've come up with so far:

(1) I have the `Trie` type, which has a private `_nodes` member of type `Trie.INodeCollection`.

(2) The `Trie.INodeCollection` interface has the following members:

```
interface INodeCollection
{
    bool TryGetNode(char key, out Trie node);
    INodeCollection Add(char key, Trie node);
    IEnumerable<Trie> GetNodes();
}
```

(3) There are three implementations of this interface:

```
class SingleNode : INodeCollection
{
    internal readonly char _key;
    internal readonly Trie _trie;

    public SingleNode(char key, Trie trie)
    { /*...*/ }

    // Add returns a SmallNodeCollection.
}

class SmallNodeCollection : INodeCollection
{
    const int MaximumSize = 8; // ?

    internal readonly List<KeyValuePair<char, Trie>> _nodes;

    public SmallNodeCollection(SingleNode node, char key, Trie trie)
    { /*...*/ }

    // Add adds to the list and returns the current instance until MaximumSize,
    // after which point it returns a LargeNodeCollection.
}

class LargeNodeCollection : INodeCollection
{
    private readonly Dictionary<char, Trie> _nodes;

    public LargeNodeCollection(SmallNodeCollection nodes, char key, Trie trie)
    { /*...*/ }

    // Add adds to the dictionary and returns the current instance.
}
```

(4) When a `Trie` is first constructed, its `_nodes` member is `null`. The first call to `Add` creates a `SingleNode`, and subsequent calls to `Add` go from there, according to the steps described above.

Does this make sense? This feels like an improvement in the sense that it *somewhat* reduces the "bulkiness" of a `Trie` (nodes are no longer full-blown `Dictionary<char, Trie>` objects until they have a sufficient number of children). However, it has also become significantly more complex. Is it too convoluted? Have I taken a complicated route to achieve something that should've been straightforward?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you need each node to have something which *effectively* implements `IDictionary<char, Trie>`. You could write your own custom implementation which varies its internal structure based on how many subnodes it has:

- For a single subnode, use just a `char` and a `Trie`
- For a small number, use a `List<Tuple<char, Trie>>` or a `LinkedList<Tuple<char,Trie>>`
- For a large number, use a `Dictionary<char, Trie>`

(Having just seen leppie's answer, this is the kind of hybrid approach he talks about, I believe.)

Comment: You could also compress the tail, like the single subnode case.

Answer (score 3):

Implementing it as a Dictionary, in my mind, isn't implementing a Trie - that's implementing a Dictionary of Dictionaries.

When I've implemented a trie I've done it the same way as suggested by Damien_The_Unbeliever (+1 there):

```
public class TrieNode
{
  TrieNode[] Children = new TrieNode[no_of_chars];
}
```

This ideally requires then that your trie will only support a limited subset of characters indicated by `no_of_chars` and that you can map input characters to output indices.  E.g. if supporting A-Z then you would naturally map A to 0 and Z to 25.

When you then need to add/remove/check existence of a node you then do something like this:

```
public TrieNode GetNode(char c)
{
  //mapping function - could be a lookup table, or simple arithmetic
  int index = GetIndex(c);
  //TODO: deal with the situation where 'c' is not supported by the map
  return Children[index];
}
```

In real cases I've seen this optimized so that AddNode, for example, would take a `ref TrieNode` so that the node can be newed on demand and automatically placed into the parent TrieNode's `Children` in the correct place.

You could also use a Ternary Search Tree instead as the memory overhead for a trie can be pretty crazy (especially if you intend to support all 32k of unicode characters!) and the TST performance is rather impressive (and also supports prefix & wildcard searching as well as hamming searches).  Equally, TSTs can natively support all unicode characters without having to do any mapping; since they work on a greater-than/less-than/equals operation instead of an absolute index value.

I took the code [from here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/tst.aspx) and adapted it slightly (it was written before generics).

I think you'll be pleasantly surprised by TSTs; once I had one implemented I steered away from Tries altogether.

The only tricky thing is keeeping the TST balanced; an issue you don't have with Tries.

Comment: sorry - I appreciate that this doesn't necessarily answer the question of how to implement - just offering an alternative :)

Answer (score 3):

If your characters are from a limited set (e.g. only uppercase latin alphabet), then you can store a 26 element array, and each lookup is just

```
Trie next = store[c-'A']
```

where c is the current lookup character.

Comment: nodes with arrays as the store is my preferred way of doing it - can't think of a more lightweight way of doing it

Comment: I'm looking for a more general case. That said, I'm willing to accept that perhaps a trie is really not ever appropriate as a "general case" data structure, in which case, maybe it only makes sense in scenarios like this (where the node structure can be simplified to a plain array).

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways, but using a singly link list is probably the simplest and lightweight.

I would do some tests to see the amount of child nodes each node has. If not much (say 20 or less), the link list approach should be faster than a hashtable. You could also do a hybrid approach depending on the amount of child nodes.