# What is the fastest way to filter a list of strings when making an Intellisense/Autocomplete list?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, linq, intellisense

I'm writing an Intellisense/Autocomplete like the one you find in Visual Studio. It's all fine up until when the list contains probably 2000+ items.

I'm using a simple LINQ statement for doing the filtering:

```
var filterCollection = from s in listCollection
                       where s.FilterValue.IndexOf(currentWord,     
                       StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
                       orderby s.FilterValue
                       select s;
```

I then assign this collection to a WPF Listbox's ItemSource, and that's the end of it, works fine.

Noting that, the Listbox is also virtualised as well, so there will only be at most 7-8 visual elements in memory and in the visual tree.

However the caveat right now is that, when the user types extremely fast in the richtextbox, and on every key up I execute the filtering + binding, there's this semi-race condition, or out of sync filtering, like the first key stroke's filtering could still be doing it's filtering or binding work, while the fourth key stroke is also doing the same.

I know I could put in a delay before applying the filter, but I'm trying to achieve a seamless filtering much like the one in Visual Studio.

I'm not sure where my problem exactly lies, so I'm also attributing it to IndexOf's string operation, or perhaps my list of string's could be optimised in some kind of index, that could speed up searching.

Any suggestions of code samples are much welcomed.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you verified that this is in fact the bottleneck?  I am just curious if there is other code that may be contributing and without profiling you cannot be sure where the bottleneck is. +1 by the way, I love questions like this.

Comment: Hey Andrew, I'm glad I asked an enlightening question :). It's just an assumption, I'm alluding to either filtering or binding to the control that's the bottleneck. I'm also not entirely sure if you can actually have an intellisense/autocomplete list feature that's extremely performant with so many items and growing. I'm not exactly good with using profiling tools, do you have any good recommendation's as to how I can profile this? I've tried the one inside visual studio, however the pretty graph points to Application.Run... =(

Comment: Are you sure that the ListBox is virtualised properly, as this actual filter code should run in about a millisecond?

Comment: Positive it's virtualised. Like I mentioned, it's fast up till it hits the thousands range.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest trying to cap your result set at some number of items and seeing if the problem goes away. That is, you might have 5000 to choose from, but try to return no more than say 100, even if more match. Say:

```
var filterCollection = (from s in listCollection
  where s.FilterValue.IndexOf(currentWord,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)>=0
  orderby s.FilterValue
  select s).Take(100);
```

If your problem goes away, the slowdown may be caused by too many items being returned for the listbox. I am not sure that the problem will go away, since the ListBox is virtualized, but it's worth a shot. You can also try the same thing, but limiting the result of the filtering to 100 items, before the sort (i.e., orderby) and see if that helps. It's more efficient to do it in this order, anyways:

```
var filterCollection = (from s in listCollection
  where s.FilterValue.IndexOf(currentWord,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)>=0
  select s).Take(100)
           .OrderBy(s => s.FilterValue);
```

The bottom line is determining if the problem is a function of the number of items returned and assigned to filterColection or of the initial number of items, or both.

Answer (score 1):

Latency is not your problem if you have a result set of 2000 items. I'm making some large assumptions here, but you only really need to return 500 items maximum - your user will keep typing to narrow the result set until it is an acceptable size to browse through.

You should optimize the common case (I'm assuming where it will end up with say ~50 items) - if your user is scrolling through a small list of 2000 items, something else is wrong and the interface needs more work.

Comment: That's quite a valid point, since the point of the feature is to narrow down the result. However, theoritcally if they just typed 'p' and every single of 20,000 (say) results, then that's 20,000 items to sift through to do a contains/indexof on, and furthermore if the user really only just typed p only and decided to scroll down the list for fun, or for some weird reason, then it's still legitimate, so capping the return size may not be exactly desirable.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that your filter performs `O(n)` (where `n` is the total number of items to autocomplete from), that is, it has to go through *every* item to figure out which ones match.  The more items you have, the worse the the filter will perform.

Instead of using a list, try using a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).  Tries perform `O(m)`, where `m` is the number of characters in the string.  This means the size of the dataset does not affect the performance of the lookup.

In [Promptu](http://www.promptulauncher.com/download-0.9-beta.php) (an app launcher I wrote), I use tries in the intellisense/autocomplete.  If you want to see an example of tries in action, you can download it and try it out.

Comment: That's what I was thinking in terms of runtime cost. I had suggestions about implementing a Trie, I haven't actually come up with an implementation of one though. Not exactly good with puting a concept into code. Do you know of any Trie builder sample code around that I could reference? Thanks.

Comment: @Winston: Unfortunately, I don't have any code that I could give out, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665317 might help you.  The idea is fairly straightforward - it's just a bunch of nested character dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

A really simple optimization is

```
if(currentWord.StartsWith(lastWord))
```

you can filter on the list of filtered items returned by the last query. That is, unless you reduce the number of items returned by your LINQ query as suggested by some of the other answers. You could always store what's in the query in a variable and then do the Take(100) afterward although you'll need to make sure LINQ's lazy execution doesn't bite you in that case.

On the binding side, rather than replace the entire collection you can use an `ObservableCollection` and just add/remove items from it. It would be a good idea to invert what your filter returns if you're going to do that but you'd see a much quicker response and wouldn't see such a big performance hit if the user is typing quickly.

Comment: I was going to apply this technique but haven't had some time around it, my idea was simply, for every key press, I save the currentWord with the set of filtered out collection, in a dictionary, so when the user backspaces, I'll already have on hand a filtered collection. Is it more heavy to replace the entire ItemsSource vs modifying an existing bound collection?

Comment: Replacing the source is much slower in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your "race condition".

```
orderby s.FilterValue
```

Consider the letter sequence d, o, g.

- "d" starts running and will match say 30% of the set. 6000 items must be ordered.
- "do" starts running and will match say 6% of the set. 1200 items must be ordered.
- "dog" starts running and will match say 0.5% of the set. 100 items must be ordered.

When considering the different workloads of each event, it is no surprise that the last event will finish before the first and second event.

The most correct behavior I can imagine is to prevent the binding for any prior active events when an event starts.  If you can prevent the binding by halting execution on those events, so much the better.  Recall those missles, they don't have targets any more.